# Accessing the XML response of a 500 error on SOAP request

Tags: c#, soap

I try to create an application that call a SOAP endpoint.

```
private static void CallWebService()
{
    var url = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx";

    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(url);
    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

    IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

    asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    string soapResult;
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
    {
        Console.Write(webResponse.ToString());
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
            Console.Write(soapResult);        
    }
}
```

My issue concerns the webresponse. the function by itself works and I do have exceptions when I Have. Now, what I need is to get the content of the XML and get faultstring content. As the code work, I do return an exception with error 500. I don't know how to extract the XML content provided as return body. Here I want to extract the following :

`System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---&gt; System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (5, 20). ---&gt; System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed completely the code and used HttpClient.

`await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` is returning the response. And i can also get the status code. I convert the **soapResponse** string into XDocument in order to extract the first line of the **faultstring** content returned as response

```
public static async Task Main()
 {
     var url = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx";
     var xmlStr = 
         @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
             <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                 <soap:Body>
                     <Add xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
                         <intA></intA>
                         <intB>100</intB>
                     </Add>
                 </soap:Body>
             </soap:Envelope>";


     using var client = new HttpClient();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/Add");
     var stringContent = new StringContent(xmlStr, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

     var response = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
     Console.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
     Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
     Console.WriteLine((int) response.StatusCode);

     var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(soapResponse);
     if (document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "faultstring") != null)
     {
         var errMessageElt = document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "faultstring");
         if (errMessageElt.Value != null)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("******************************");
             int index = errMessageElt.Value.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
             string firstline = index == -1 ? errMessageElt.Value : errMessageElt.Value.Substring(0, index);
             
             Console.WriteLine(firstline);
             Console.WriteLine("******************************");
         }
     }
     Console.WriteLine(soapResponse);
 }
```